# Can I have business logic to check if a resource is expired and generate new ones before I return in tastypie?

Tags: tastypie

My models have "created" timestamp on them. And they expire after a day and should be re-created.

How can I have code that when client tries to `GET` the resources from TastyPie API, I check if the resource is expired and do business logic. I know it is possible to use filter to filter out the expired resources, but can I remove the expired resources and create new resources and then return them in the result?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. For example, you can override your resource's `obj_get()` method.

Its source code is located here: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L1895, and looks like this:

```py
def obj_get(self, request=None, **kwargs):
    """
    A ORM-specific implementation of ``obj_get``.

    Takes optional ``kwargs``, which are used to narrow the query to find
    the instance.
    """
    try:
        base_object_list = self.get_object_list(request).filter(**kwargs)
        object_list = self.apply_authorization_limits(request, base_object_list)
        stringified_kwargs = ', '.join(
            ["%s=%s" % (k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items()]
        )

        if len(object_list) <= 0:
            raise self._meta.object_class.DoesNotExist(
                "Couldn't find an instance of '%s' which matched '%s'." %
                (self._meta.object_class.__name__, stringified_kwargs)
            )
        elif len(object_list) > 1:
            raise MultipleObjectsReturned(
                "More than '%s' matched '%s'." % (
                    self._meta.object_class.__name__,
                    stringified_kwargs
                )
            )

        return object_list[0]
    except ValueError:
        raise NotFound(
            "Invalid resource lookup data provided (mismatched type)."
        )
```

You can check `object_list` obtained within that code, and then apply appropriate actions.

Alternatively you can override [`get_detail()` method](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L1139), which specifically handles `GET` requests to the single resource, by using `obj_get()` on the way.

Comment: Thank you very much! You really helped me to get started. But I still have not figured out what exactly should I override. It seems to me that there are 2 sets of methods. One set get multiple/one django object(s), they are obj_get and obj_get_list. the other set is get the resource get_details and get_list. Which set do you think I should override?

Comment: And there is a get_object_list that returns a QuerySet o_O. I'm really confused.

Comment: A little more digging that reveals that get_object_list is even lower level and used by obj_get_list and a lot other things.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is by overriding the `get_object_list` method. This is documented here: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#per-request-alterations-to-the-queryset